# Python Module not found, relative folder. Can't figure it out

Tags: python, python-import

There are a million answers for this on Google but I can't seem to apply any of the fixes and get the expected result! Hopefully someone can help me here?

I have used Python in the past but it's been a while, I am re-writing an old project from last year using SQLAlchemy and SQLite3.

Problem is, I can't seem to get my tests to play nice. I am trying to separate my test database from production database, so I have the following file structure:

```
    .
├── fleet_manager
│   ├── controller
│   │   └── customer_controller.py
│   ├── database.db
│   ├── fleet_manager.py
│   ├── model
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── models.py
│   └── view
├── Pipfile
├── Pipfile.lock
└── tests
    ├── context.py
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── test_customer_controller.py
    ├── test.db
    └── test_models.py
```

So I have created a context.py file and in here I have my SQLAlchemy engine/session factory. It is this file that my test files can't find.

```py
# test_models.py

from mamba import description, context, it, before
from expects import expect, equal, be_a, be_none
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Table
from sqlalchemy.engine import Engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker


from context import Session # < this mofo here
from fleet_manager.model.models import (
    Equipment,
    EquipmentType,
    Discipline,
    Size,
    Make,
    Model,
    Customer,
    Base)
```

So basically the above file is not finding context at all

```py
# context.py

from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///tests/test.db', echo=True)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
```

This is the error I get (omitted the excess trace):

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tests/test_models'
```

I have tried a bunch of stuff so far. I have tried modifying the path using os.path, as well as using .context as opposed to context but still nothing.
Originally I had this problem when trying to access my models.py but that's because I forgot to put **init**.py in the folder!

Can anyone help me here? Ripping my hair out.

Comment: how do you launch test_models.py ?  maybe it could work with `from .context import Session` or `from tests.context import Session` ?

Comment: Currently running it using `pipenv run mamba test_models.py`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one quick way tosave you from ripping hair out

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/path/to/your/package_or_module")
```

Comment: That worked...wtf, I already done that before! So that was easy, what are the cons? Must be plenty.

Comment: use it all the time, con if the import is from another project then things can get messy, and sharing code between people

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your tests directory is not in your python path. And it wont be by default. You are trying to import from that directory using

```
from context import Session
```

and it fails. As you would be executing from your base directory, you can do absolute import from that directory using

```
from tests.context import Session
```

Or use relative imports like this.

```
from .context import Session
```